# 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, async-await

While trying to check the result of an asynchronous method I'm getting the below error.

Neither I tried `await container.ExistsAsync().Result` nor `bool result = await container.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` worked.

Where am I going wrong?

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task StorageAccountConnectionTest()
{
    var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(_mockFuncXTransConfiguration.Object.StorageAccountName, _mockFuncXransConfiguration.Object.StorageAccountKey);
    var cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
    var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(_mockFuncXTransConfiguration.Object.BlobName);
    bool result = await container.ExistsAsync().Result;
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Either `await` the result asynchronously or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` it synchronously -- not both. (In this case there seems to be no reason at all to go synchronous.)

Comment: You can't `await Task.Result`, you just use `await Task`, so use `bool result = await container.ExistsAsync();`

Comment: Wrong duplicate link. This is not about Task not having GetAwaiter, it is as the question states, about `bool` not having GetAwaiter, and that is because this is a hodge podge of synchronous and asynchronous code. `ExistsAsync().Result` will force an immediate block and wait for the result to be available, with all the possibilities of deadlock that can occur. There is no *need* for `await` here, or rather, there should not be a call to `Result` here, and instead the task from `ExistsAsync()` should be awaited to get the boolean result. The duplicate is about something quite different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're currently trying to wait the result of the task:

```
bool result = await container.GetAwaiter().GetResult().Result;
```

Which is redundant, but also a deadlock problem waiting to happen.  (Almost never call `.Result` directly.)  Instead, `await` the task which produces the result:

```
bool result = await container.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments below, I'd missed that the `container` is already a task.  Since the whole method is already `async`, you can skip all of the `GetAwaiter` stuff and just await it directly:

```
bool result = await container;
```

**Edit:** As further pointed out in comments, it looks like the code you provided doesn't match the code you're actually using in the screen shot.  The `container` itself isn't the task, but has a method which returns the task you want:

```
bool result = await container.ExistsAsync();
```

Comment: The method is async already - there's no need to use .GetAwaiter.GetResult() at all. It can simply be awaited.

Comment: Or she could just await the task : `bool result = await container`

Comment: @David, could you point out where to read about `GetAwaiter().GetResult();` should be used instead of `Result`? From MS help for `TaskAwaiter.GetResult`: This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Comment: FYI, the code should be `await container.ExistsAsync();`.  The example code is all messed up but the included screenshot shows the appropriate method call that returns `Task<bool>`

Comment: Yeah actually your last two bits of code would not compile, this needs to be fixed

Comment: @maccettura: Should be fixed now.  Looks like a pretty good example of a case where the OP artificially modified code while posting it, instead of just copying/pasting.  Thanks for catching it!